# http apache server doesn't handle php files

Tags: php, apache, centos

In my centos:

`php -v`  works gives 5.4 version

the httpd server is running and working

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

this line of code is in httpd.conf, why the index.php file isn't hanled?

is there anyway that I can check if its all ok?

output of rpm -qa | grep php:

```
php54-pdo-5.4.26-1.ius.el6.x86_64
php54-mbstring-5.4.26-1.ius.el6.x86_64
php54-common-5.4.26-1.ius.el6.x86_64
php54-mysql-5.4.26-1.ius.el6.x86_64
php54-ldap-5.4.26-1.ius.el6.x86_64
php54-gd-5.4.26-1.ius.el6.x86_64
php54-mcrypt-5.4.26-1.ius.el6.x86_64
```

also I get this error after sudo yum install php -y:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-5.4.26-32.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.26-32.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.26-32.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.26-32.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.26-32.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.26-32.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.26-32.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.26-32.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First insure that you have the PHP Apache module installed.

```
ls -l /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
```

If you don't have that file then you may just have the php-cli (command line interface) installed without the php Apache httpd module.  To install run the command:

```
sudo yum install php -y
```

Then restart your httpd server:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

For Apache httpd to process index.php files, you need to update your DirectoryIndex to handle PHP directory indexes.

On Centos edit the file:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Search for the line starting:

```
DirectoryIndex
```

And add the following to the space delimited list of index filenames:

```
index.php
```

Directory index files will be recognized in the order they are defined.

You will also need to restart your httpd service using:

```
sudo service httpd reload
```

Alternatively you can use the apachectl utility to reload httpd gracefully

```
sudo apachectl graceful
```

Comment: I've did what you've sayd and restarted the server, but the index.php still isn't handled, cant figure out why is that

Comment: How about if you call it directly by adding index.php to the URL?

Comment: yes thats what I've did, it gives me text of the php code in my browser

Comment: I have revised the Answer,  make sure the 'php' module is installed and not just the 'php-cli' command line interface.

Comment: added output in my question

Comment: Yes you need to run the yum command I added in the answer and restart PHP.

Comment: well :)), looks like a problem is a bit deeper than I tought, can you give me a last hint on how to avoid those errors i adde on my question?)

Comment: You existing packages are older than the current ones.  Try this command first then reboot and retry your install:  yum update -y

Comment: also I don't have a php.conf file

Comment: tried to use --skip-broken, but still no luck...thanks anyway

Comment: You may have a 3rd party yum repository that is conflicting with the main centos files.  Check /etc/yum.repos.d,  you can exclude certain repos using the yum --disablerepo parameter.  Also, (Hopefully your not using SSH to connect), but you may try:  'sudo yum remove openssl', you will probably have to also uninstall some dependencies, then reinstall them.  Alternatively,  you might consider starting with a clean install of Centos 6 from a freshly downloaded DVD ISO.  Sadly, now we are out far outside of the scope of the question.